# the ephemeral and the eternal

Tags: word-usage

When I looked up the word ephemeral usage in Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ephemeral%20and%20the%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cephemeral%20and%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20eternal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20permanent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20lasting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20enduring%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20durable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20transitory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20swift%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bephemeral%20and%20the%20contingent%3B%2Cc0), I noticed it is commonly used with the opposite words together. For example,

> The ephemeral and the eternal
>
> The ephemeral and the enduring
>
> The ephemeral and the permanent

What does it imply?

For example:

> The ephemeral and the eternal of face of Las Vegas.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the phrase "The ephemeral and the eternal face of Las Vegas"?  Or are you asking about the general meaning of the phrase *the ephemeral and the eternal*?  If it's the latter, this phrase has no special meaning.  The meaning is literal: *the things that don't last and the things that do*

Answer (score 1):

**The ephemeral** refers to the fleeting, the evanescent.

**The eternal** refers to the unchanging, to that which remains the same forever.

When yoked as modifiers of the same thing, the intention is paradox.

Specifically with regard to Las Vegas, a gambling "mecca", with lights that flash and go out,  entertainment acts by stars who will fade into obscurity, a sea of changing faces, people who bring money and leave without it, or rarely the opposite, there's plenty that is ephemeral; what is eternal is the fact that it is ever-changing, that it is constantly in flux, that there is an endless throng of people visiting the place.